# Why does `mongodb.client.connect().db(dbname)` work?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a piece of code, and I don't understand why, please help

```
const Mongodb = {
  client: new MongoClient(dbconfig.dbUrl, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  }),
  oper: null,
  db: null,
  dbName: ''
};

const connectdb = async (dbName = dbconfig.dbName) => {
  if (Mongodb.oper) { 
    if (dbName !== Mongodb.dbName) {
      Mongodb.db = Mongodb.oper.db(dbName); //Why does code on this line work?
      Mongodb.dbName = dbName;
    }
    return Mongodb.db;
  }
  Mongodb.oper = await Mongodb.client.connect();
  return await connectdb(dbName);
};
```

I think this function `connectdb` will run twice

- first step, `Mongodb.oper` will be filled with an object from `Mongodb.client.connect()`
- Second step, `Mongodb.db` will be filled with an object from `Mongodb.oper.db(dbName)`, that means `Mongodb.db` will be filled with an object from `Mongodb.client.connect().db(dbName)`, because of the first step.

I checked mongodb document, there's no function `Mongodb.client.connect().db()` in the Mongodb document, there're `Mongodb.client.connect()` and `Mongodb.client.db()`.

This confuses me, why does `Mongodb.db = Mongodb.oper.db(dbName);` work? It should throw an error, shouldn't it?

Comment: See [MongoDB NodeJS Driver - Connection Guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/connection/).

Comment: @prasad_ I checked that, but there's no `Mongodb.client.connect().db() `

Comment: `Mongodb.client.connect().db()` - The `Mongodb` is defined in your code.: `const Mongodb = { ...`. So, you cannot find it in the documentation. In general, the code to work with the database is written using the MongoDB Node JS Driver APIs (you can look in the earlier provided link).